# Select Default Radio Button depending on value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Radio button names and id's coming from database.Here is what i have done.

```
foreach (var radiobtn in Model.PrintLocations)
          {
            if (int.Parse(radiobtn.Value) < 3)
                {                                                        
                 <td>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PrintLocation, radiobtn.Value.ToString())
                    @radiobtn.Text
                 </td>
                }
            }
```

My requirement is select radio button having id `1`  will be selected by default.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
foreach (var radiobtn in Model.PrintLocations)
{
    if (int.Parse(radiobtn.Value) < 3)
    {                                                        
     <td>
        if(yourCondition)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PrintLocation, radiobtn.Value.ToString())
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PrintLocation, radiobtn.Value.ToString(), new { @checked = "checked" })
        }
        @radiobtn.Text
     </td>
    }
}
```

other way (if you don't want a "dirty" html code) is selecting the radio by javascript (or jquery)

hope I've helped

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RadioButtonListFor helper.

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, you can just use [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/). It got this helper built in. Otherwise you can get and adjust the code for it from [here](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc). An example of use of such helper you can get from [here](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation/V2#inputs) (scrool down to **CheckBoxList / RadioButtonList**).
The beauty of this helper is that `PrintLocations` can be any `IEnumerable` - not only a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

**Quick code example:**

```
@(Html.Bootstrap().RadioButtonListFor(
    m => m.PrintLocation,
    m => m.PrintLocations,
    loc => loc.Value,
    loc => loc.Text)
    .SelectedValues(loc => loc.Value == 1))
```

I suggest this helper for two reasons. First, because I built it :) Second, it uses fluent syntax.

There is another cool helper for similar thing that does not produce Bootstrap related markup: [CheckBoxList(For)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension). Check it out as well!